# Bootstrap 3 dropdown button height and search

Tags: php, css, button

I'm having a little problem with bootstrap 3. I tried for the whole day to solve and searched everything in internet even used FireBug but didn't help.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRTns.png]

The button of dropdown is higher than the menu and its going outside the menu.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <?php if(!is_array(session( 'thisUser'))): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo URL('register') ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <?php echo T('Register') ?></a>
  <a href="<?php echo URL('login') ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> <?php echo T('Login') ?></a>
  <?php else: ?>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle text-notransform" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      <img src="<?php echo URL(session_get('preferences', 'avatar')) ?>" width="24px">&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <?php echo session_get('thisUser', 'username') ?> <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li>
        <div class="navbar-login">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <p class="text-center">
                <img src="<?php echo URL(session_get('preferences', 'avatar')) ?>" width="200px">
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <p class="text-left"><strong><?php echo session_get('thisUser', 'username') ?></strong>
              </p>
              <p class="text-left small">
                <?php echo session_get( 'thisUser', 'email') ?>
              </p>
              <br />
              <p class="text-left">
                <a href="<?php echo URL(T('setting-slug', 'settings')) ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm">
                  <?php echo T( 'Settings') ?>
                </a>
                <?php echo event( 'user_menu', '') ?>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <div class="navbar-login navbar-login-session">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <p>
                <a href="<?php echo URL('logout') ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">
                  <?php echo T( 'Logout') ?>
                </a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

My second problem is with the bootstrap search I want the button search to be next to the search text not bellow it. The code is PHP function:

```
function search_box($a){
    $return .= Form::open(array('method'=>'GET', 'action'=>URL(T('directory'))));
    $return .= Form::input('q', R('q'), array('class'=>'form-control input-md', 'style'=>'margin-bottom:5px','placeholder'=>T('Type smth to search')));
    $return .= '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-primary"><i class="icon-find"></i> '.T('Search').'</button>';
    $return .= Form::close();
    $return .= '<div class="clearfix"><br /></div>';
    return $return;
}
```

(For image of the search is the same as the above link)
 Can someone tell me how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show css, check <p class="text-center"> for height.

Comment: the css is the default of bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

On your searchbox($a) function, try removing `btn-md` class from button.

Comment: No change, it still under the search text

Comment: can you provide a link to the generated html so we can inspect it live?